# How to import Python data to postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql

I found such a code online but I am trying to edit it to link Python data to postgresql. I am really new to coding so I would really appreciate your help.

```
import psycopg2
import sys

connection = None

connection = psycopg2.connect("host='localhost' db='football'           
user ='postgres' password='password'")   
cur = con.cursor()
con.commit()

try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    # Create a new record
    sql = "INSERT INTO `Games` (`email`, `password`) VALUES (%s, %s)"
    cursor.execute(sql, ('webmaster@python.org', 'very-secret'))
except SyntaxError as e:
    print("There was an error: {}".format(e))


connection.commit()

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
# Read a single record
    sql = "SELECT row[5]"
    cursor.execute(sql, ('row [5]',))
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    print(result)
finally:
    connection.close()
```

Comment: That code should indeed insert data from Python to PostgreSQL. What exactly is it that you're not able to do?

Comment: Thanks for your comment bernie. I got my csv data into Python using Pydev on Eclipse where I managed to clean it. Now I want to send that data into different tables on postgresql. What should I do?

Comment: Can you edit into your question a small example of your data and your table structure?

Comment: I don't think this is the right move. I am dealing with huge data and want to import it to postgresql with the least interference possible.

Comment: for a fact I am getting invalid syntax for "try" or line 17.

Comment: You're getting that error because you need an `except [SomeError]:` clause on your `try:` statement.

Comment: That worked :) I am still struggling as it says there is an invalid syntax for "finally"

Answer (score 0):

Your `try` statement needs to be paired with an `except`.  The purpose of `try`/`except` is to catch any errors thrown in your `try` block gracefully.  But without an `except`, `try` isn't very useful.

```
try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    # Create a new record
        sql = "INSERT INTO `Games` (`email`, `password`) VALUES (%s, %s)"
        cursor.execute(sql, ('webmaster@python.org', 'very-secret'))
except SyntaxError as e:
    print("There was an error: {}".format(str(e)))
```

Your actual `psycopg2` code looks about right.

Comment: worked. one more issue:     import psycopg2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'

Despite the fact I downloaded it. What to do?

Comment: OKAY it all worked but when running the code I get "Error %s % e" so technically it is failing..

Comment: See updates, try wrapping `e` with `str()`.  But you don't really need to print out `e` at all, you can just use `pass` or some other custom print statement.  The main issue you were facing was the incomplete `try` syntax.

Comment: But I am just wondering why the data does not get uploaded to postgresql. somehow trying to follow these steps: pythonspot.com/en/python-database-postgresql